# How to listen to method invokation using Dart reflection?

Tags: flutter, dart, methods, reflection, dart-mirrors

i read a bit about dart mirrors but I did not figure out `how to listen to method invocation using dart reflection`.

**Use Case:**

Buttons in Flutter can have an `onTap()` method which is invoked when an user taps on that button.

**I would like to listen to that invokation of `onTap()` using dart reflection** to fire my own code when that happens...

how to realize that?

**EDIT:**

I want to inject code to a function that has a specific annotation...how to do this?

Comment: if it is an invocation why do you need to listen to it? did you get what i mean?

Comment: I want to track the user...When he clicks a button I want to track that. I need this for a research Projekt at my university.

Comment: see my edit please

Answer (score 1):

It is *impossible* - Flutter *completely disables* the reflection (`dart:mirror`). So you need to find other ways.

See this for the disabled reflection: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/1150

**EDIT**

Given you updated question, you need a **code generator**. For example, the json_annotation package.

If that does not help, you may need things like https://github.com/alibaba-flutter/aspectd (Warn: that project may or may not be good).

Comment: I took a look at json_annotation, but that is not what I need. I don´t want to create code outside of a function as separate function, I want to inject code to a specific function at build time, so that after build was finished an original function got modified in the way that is has some lines of code more at the end whose I injected through some logic, let it be reflection or whatever...I search for a way to do that. My goal is: Developing a smart way to let developers annotate a function or even not to annotate anything and at the same time my code reads and injects code to it.

Comment: Through this way I could inject code to tap-functions (click-Function) of buttons for example whose would then execute my lne of code whose track the buttons clicks...with this data I want to save the events and do later on same analysis on them, e.g. how did the user navigate through the app? whose actions did he do? what buttons did he click etc.

Comment: @skm Then look at aspectd. As far as I know, there is almost nothing to achieve your goal, since dart is a so static language, unlike JS

Comment: I am struggling with aspectD...didn´t get it to work yet. Saw some articles whose told good about it...will try getting it to work...do you have a working sample right to start from? the example in git seems not to work out of the box...

Comment: @skm aspectd really lack of documentations... I also do not have one, but you may post a issue there asking for help

Comment: thank you very much for your help. I´ll give it another try and if it would not work I´ll try to contact the creator or post an issue.